# I don't see my picture but only the alt attribute

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I don't understand why I cannot see my image, I mean I just see the alt attribute instead of the picture. Here is my code :

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

const Cards = (props) => {

    return (
        <>
            <div  id="card" className={"card text-white bg-" + props.bootstrap + " mb-3"}
                 style={{maxWidth: 200, marginRight: 10}}>
                <div className="card-header">Test</div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <img src="test.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" className="card-img-top" alt="test" />
                    <h4 className="card-title">Description</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Cards;
```

whereas when I try this modification it works :

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import logo from './test.jpg';

const Cards = (props) => {

    return (
        <>
            <div  id="card" className={"card text-white bg-" + props.bootstrap + " mb-3"}
                 style={{maxWidth: 200, marginRight: 10}}>
                <div className="card-header">Test</div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <img src={logo} width="200px" height="200px" className="card-img-top" alt="test" />
                    <h4 className="card-title">Description</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

I don't understand why this does not work. For me the path is good.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 0):

`alt` will be presented each time the image would not load properly.

So in your case, the latter example would work properly because `logo` is actually pointing to the `jpg` image, and the image could be displayed without the `alt` string.
The first example you shared would not work because `src` doesn't have an actual pat, it only has a string that isn't resolved into an image hence no image would be loaded and the browser will present the `alt` value.

Comment: There is no a solution in order to make workable the first example ?

Answer (score 0):

on most occasions, images (static files) should be stored in your /public folder.

You can create a images folder in your public folder and then you set `src="/images/test.jpg"` instead of just "test.jpg"

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why the path change that ?

Comment: your src folder host all the javascript files but they are not built yet, eventually all your files are server from the /public/ folder when you type 'npm build' (assuming you are not using any other technologies), so your path have to be relative to /public/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import

In some case if still not work
than check `config` file as I described
Note: need to install `file-loader` package

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import logo from './test.jpg';

const Cards = (props) => {

    return (
        <>
            <div  id="card" className={"card text-white bg-" + props.bootstrap + " mb-3"}
                 style={{maxWidth: 200, marginRight: 10}}>
                <div className="card-header">Test</div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <img src={logo} width="200px" height="200px" className="card-img-top" alt="test" />
                    <h4 className="card-title">Description</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

In Config file:: MAKE SURE FOLLOWING RULES DEFINED

````
module.exports = {
 // other config
 module: {
  rules: [
    // other rules
    {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
    },
  ]
 }
}```
````

Comment: The code that you show is the second code that I posted but I want to make workable the first code

Comment: in that case you use absolute url 
e.g. "http://localhost/app/test.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

That's because webpack is configured to bundle your images and assets by using the JSX syntax. Anything within {} can be seen as a property of a component. When it's inside the src attribute it becomes a property of the src and webpack than knows what to do. If you are simply adding the string it will view the source as a string rather than an image.
The path alone will only have meaning when you convert it from a meaningless string to an object. An alternative to your first approach could be

> <img src={require('/text.jpg')} />

That should work too.

Comment: I tried `<img src={require('./test.png')} />` but it does not work I just see alt attribute

Comment: Perhaps the image is not in the same directory? Maybe you have to go down a directory?

Comment: ok this works perfectly : <img src={require('./test.png').default} />

Comment: he has a test.jpg but your code is test.png, I doubt they bother checking the code difference and just copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<img src="./test.jpg" ...
```

It should work, if the picture is in the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is : `<img src={require('./test.png').default} />`

Comment: Try the answer from above i edited. I think i used png instead of jpg that you had in your example. This way you can remove the .default.